# Redshift schema creator does not show in SVV_SCHEMA_PRIVILEGES system table

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

lets say im user `user`. I create a schema with

`CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS my_schema`

however, when I run

```
select *
from SVV_SCHEMA_PRIVILEGES
where namespace_name = 'my_schema';
```

I expect to see several records for `user` with `usage/create` privileges but this is not the case. It seems that i need to execute

```
GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA my_schema TO user;
```

in order to see my, the creator of this schema, privileges. Is this an expected behavior or am i misunderstanding something?

I am 99.99% sure that the creator of a schema has all privileges on the schema and any tables the creator adds in the schema.

Comment: `user` is both Postgres and SQL Standard [reserved word](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html). I am not sure, but you may be running into an invalid use of a reserved word.  Try double quoting it i.e. `"User"` or another common approach, start the name with an underscore  i.e. `"_user"`.  Better yet create a different name altogether.

Comment: @Belayer i tried with another user name and it has the same result as well